# Content Security Policy for self subdomains

Tags: security, http

In order to set a default-src for self it will exclude the subdomains of the origin website.

```
default-src 'self'
```

How to enable the subdomains of the self URL?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to explicitly add them with fully qualified domains:

```
default-src 'self' sub1.example.com sub2.example.com
```

Or with wildcards:

```
default-src 'self' *.example.com
```

Comment: you can also use wildcards: default-src 'self' *.example.com

Comment: I didn't think this is a correct answer the question is how to allow subdomains of the self url. Here self could be anything with your solution we need to know the self value before but what user wants is to automatically detect what self is and allow subdomains of self as well.

Comment: I don't ncessarily disagree. However this is the only way t do this. There is no `*.self` nor `includingSubdomains` type option for CSP. The automatic detection can happen server side and the apprioriate sub-domain being inserted into the policy.

Comment: Do we need to explicitly mention the `www.` and non-`www`-prefixed subdomains then? If we list only the `www` hostname then will the parent domain be included too?

Comment: Typically you pick on and redirect to the other. So as the page only loads on one domain only that should require CSP setup. It's considered bad practice to actually display the site for both addresses - though it should be accessible through both, but redirected to preferred version.

Answer (score 20):

Wanted to add one thing, the wildcard `*.mydomain.com` doesn't cover the main domain `mydomain.com` and it needs to be individually added to the policy as below.

```
default-src 'self' *.mydomain.com mydomain.com
```

Comment: Unless the main domain is the same ss `self`.